# Is there a TensorFlow.js method to add a tensor to another at a specific location?

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

Let me make the question clear. I have a tensor, just to keep it simple, with zeros. A 2D tensor with shape `[3, 3]`, call it `a`:

```
[[0,0,0],
 [0,0,0],
 [0,0,0]]
```

And I have another tensor, a 2D tensor with shape `[2, 2]`, call it `b`, and its just ones:

```
[[1,1],
 [1,1]]
```

I want to add them together, but their shapes don't match, and I can't broadcast it as well, but it's not the goal. I want the result of:

```
[[0,0,0],
 [0,1,1],
 [0,1,1]]
```

And if there would be a method, call it `insert` for now, I'd have to specify the location where I want to insert the smaller tensor (just as when slicing, defining the start location). It would look something like this:

```
a.insert(b, [1, 1])
```

I was thinking about `pad` which could produce similar results, but if there would be something like the above, what I might missed, it would be nicer.

Comment: I think that only pad is your option here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `tf.pad`, it can be done as the following

```
padded = tf.ones([2, 2]).pad([[1, 0], [1, 0]])
```